# Python inner class variable, namespace

Tags: python, class, inner-classes

```
class myouterclass(object):
                    def __init__(self,ID):
                              self.myouterclassID=myouterclassID
                              self.myinnerclass=self.MYINNERCLASS()
                    class MYINNERCLASS:
                              def __init__(self):
                                      self.myinnerclassID=myinnerclassID
```

I am trying to create an inner class and create some variables including an ID. For simplicity I would like to also use ID to define different instances of my outer class as well.

I am lacking some understanding on what I am doing wrong.

What I am trying to accomplish is to use the same name variable "ID" to define an identification for the different instances of the outer class AND also to use the same name variable "ID" to keep track of the different instances of the inner class object "myinnerclass". I am planning to create more than one instances of the innerclass and I need to have different ID to keep track of them

Thanks

Comment: Welcome tris. Can you elaborate a bit on what you're trying to accomplish? Perhaps an approach other than inner classes would be more appropriate.

Comment: Where is `myinnerclassID` coming from?

Comment: What I am trying to accomplish is to use the same name variable "ID" to define an identification for the different instances of the outer class AND also to use the same name variable "ID" to keep track of the different instances of the inner class object "myinnerclass". I am planning to create more than one instances of the innerclass and I need to have different ID to keep track of them

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you wanted that?

```
class myouterclass(object):
    def __init__(self, the_id):
        self.myouterclassID = the_id
        self.myinnerclass = self.MYINNERCLASS(the_id)

    class MYINNERCLASS:
        def __init__(self, inner_id):
            self.myinnerclassID = inner_id
    def __init__(self, inner_id):
        self.myinnerclassID = inner_id
```

Comment: Thanks Mikaelblomkvistsson, your solution is what I was looking for